# If $A$ is a $5 \times 5$ matrix with eigenvalues 2 and 3 each with algebraic multiplicity 2, $trace (A)=15$ find $det(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $A$ is a $5 \times 5$ matrix with eigenvalues 2 and 3 each with algebraic multiplicity 2. If trace of $A$ is 15 what is the value of its determinant

**My attempt** So trace is the sum of the eigenvalues (2,3 and x). Therefore $2+2+3+3+x=15$ therefore $x=5$. Hence determinant of $A$ must be $2\times 2 \times 3 \times 3 \times 5 =180$

Is that correct?

Comment: $2+2+3+3+2=12$...

Answer (score 4):

Your attempt has the right idea, but the solution to the equation $$2+2+3+3+x=15$$

is **not** $x=2$.

---

After the edit, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Except for that $2 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 2 = 12$, you are [principally] correct.

Comment: oops getting a little hurried there

Comment: I have made the changes.

Comment: After your changes answers are missing context.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Consider $f(t)={\rm det}\ (tI- A)$ Then $$ f(t)=(t-2)^2(t-3)^2 (t-C)$$ for some $C\in {\bf C}$ So ${\rm trace}\ A=15$ means that $C$ is $5$.